# How to set dynamic value to HTTP Post method fields

Tags: javascript, asp.net, http, post

I'm creating a POST method which passing parameter to payment gateway in ASP.NET.

Is there any way to set dynamic value for input field inside the POST form tag. because payment details will be different for every transaction so how could i set the value each time dynamically.

[image]

Comment: take input from the user and sent to backend ? No ?

Comment: Get input details from users like email Id,name and have to assign input hidden field inside POST form.

Answer (score 0):

as this is a asp file, you can make html content dynamic like this:

```
<%
//some server side logic.
%>
```

Comment: can you give with some example?

Answer (score 0):

I got this solution. changed to "runat='server'" and used asp:HiddenField now its working fine.[image]